# Problem in making an exe file using Pyinstaller (file made using tkinter and Custom tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I am trying to make a small application for data entry using tkinter and custom tkinter. The code runs fine in python and  I made the exe file of it using
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole try45.py

But on running the exe file it gives error labelled as "Unhandled exception in script". Details of it are attached as below,

I have also attached the image of the error. The first two lines of it say
"Failed to execute script 'try45' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Farzan Bashir\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI127522\customtkinter\assets\themes\blue.json"

and the details in next lines are,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "try45.py", line 2, in    File "", line 1027, in
> _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 688, in *load_unlocked   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "customtkinter_*init**.py", line 3, in    File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "customtkinter\widgets\customtkinter_input_dialog.py", line 4, in    File "", line 1027, in
> _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "customtkinter\widgets\customtkinter_label.py", line 4, in    File "", line 1027, in
> _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "customtkinter\widgets\customtkinter_tk.py", line 9, in   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "", line 1006, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "customtkinter\customtkinter_theme_manager.py", line 83, in    File "customtkinter\customtkinter_theme_manager.py", line 16, in load_theme FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Farzan Bashir\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI44122\customtkinter\assets\themes\blue.json'

PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: If you want help please share you code. It becomes ways easier to understand your issue.

Comment: Your code is looking for the file `blue.json`. If you wan to deploy the `.exe` that file must be included in it, otherwise you get the File not found error. Your bundled `.exe` knows to look for it in the temporary folder with `_MEI` in the name. But it isn't there because you did not specify it at build time. Read the documenation about creating a `.spec` file that will allow you to include needed resources in the `.exe`.

Comment: if you use files with data/resources then you have to manually add them to PyInstaller configuration (file `.spec`) because PyInstaller doesn't check what resources you use.You can also add it in command line `--add-data "blue.json;."`. You can find more details in PyInstaller documentation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more furas. I am very new to Python exe making and cant quite get it. Just to tell you the file i am trying to convert to exe is named as try45.py. So can you please write the complete command i have to give in command console

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem, adding custom tkinter folder data in site-packages folder into console command solved it, here:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "C:\Users\(your pc name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\(your python version that has custom tkinter)\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter;customtkinter/"  "<Path to Python Script>"
```

Comment: Since you're adding data from our local computer. Will the shared .exe compile and run without the directory defined in the `--add-data` flag in the target user's PC?

Answer (score 2):

On your terminal navigate to your directory that contains your GUI using
`cd<path>`
Then use this exact command to get your .exe

`pyinstaller -F BooyooToDo.py --collect-all customtkinter -w`

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me! If it wouldn't, the best case scenario would be to follow CustomTKinter's creator procedure: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Packaging#windows-pyinstaller-auto-py-tp-exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Have tried many different solutions, including the one suggested by "noor osama", which did not work for me. What eventually worked for me was the following code:

```
conda activate <env>
cd <location of .py file>
pyinstaller -F <.py file> --collect-all customtkinter
```

Hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I tried "noor osama" solution, but got a problem:
pypaperclip(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip')

So I tried using "auto-py-to-exe" and added the package "pyperclip" in "--hidden-import" under the "Advance" option.